# added styling to my table and it stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made an order form in java and html css everything was going well until I decided to put some styling in my code and now it doesn't reset post it basically does nothing its probably something small but I cant find it even when I use the javascript console.

It needs to show the amount and I need to add a discount that only works on monday and Friday

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Order Form</title>
    <link href="pl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>




    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1><span class="blue">&lt;</span>faiz<span class="blue">&gt;</span> <span class="yellow">pizza</span></h1>
<form>

<table class="container">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><h1>Pizza</h1></th>
        <th><h1>Image</h1></th>
        <th><h1>Quantity</h1></th>
        <th><h1>Price</h1></th>
        <th><h1>Total</h1></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>margherita</td>
        <td><img src="Pizza_Margherita_stu_spivack-removebg-preview.png" alt="margherita" height="400" width="400"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="QtyA"></td>
        <td>€3.00</td>

        <td id="TotalA"></td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tuna</td>
        <td><img src="Tuna_Treat-7268.png" alt="Tuna" height="400" width="400"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="QtyB"></td>
        <td>€14.00</td>
        <td id="TotalB"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fourcheese</td>
        <td><img src="4_Cheese-7262.png" alt="fourcheese"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="QtyC"></td>
        <td>€5.50</td>

        <td id="TotalC"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>double pepperoni</td>
        <td><img src="Double_Pepperoni-7260.png" alt="pep" height="400" width="400"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="QtyD"></td>
        <td>€5.50</td>

        <td id="TotalD"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pizza</td>
        <td>ef</td>
        <td>fwrf</td>
        <td>ref</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>refe</td>
        <td>erf</td>
        <td>erf</td>
        <td>ref</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Get Grand Total"></td>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>




</table>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

    var qtyBoxA = document.getElementById('QtyA');
    var qtyBoxB = document.getElementById('QtyB');
    var qtyBoxC = document.getElementById('QtyC');
    var qtyBoxD = document.getElementById('QtyD');
    var totBoxA = document.getElementById('TotalA');
    var totBoxB = document.getElementById('TotalB');
    var totBoxC = document.getElementById('TotalC');
    var totBoxD = document.getElementById('TotalD');

    var grandTot = document.getElementById('grandTotal');
    var btnGetTot = document.querySelector("input[type=button]");
    var btnReset = document.querySelector("input[type=reset]");


    qtyBoxA.addEventListener("change", calc);
    qtyBoxB.addEventListener("change", calc);
    qtyBoxC.addEventListener("change", calc);
    qtyBoxD.addEventListener("change", calc);
    btnGetTot.addEventListener("click", getGrandTotal);
    btnReset.addEventListener("click", reset);

    var gt = null;

    function calc() {

        var priceA = 3;
        var priceB = 4;
        var priceC = 5.50;
        var priceD = 5.50;
        gt = 0;


        var qtyA = parseInt(qtyBoxA.value, 10);
        var qtyB = parseInt(qtyBoxB.value, 10);
        var qtyC = parseInt(qtyBoxC.value, 10);
        var qtyD = parseInt(qtyBoxD.value, 10);


        if (!isNaN(qtyA)) { totBoxA.textContent = qtyA * priceA; gt += +totBoxA.textContent; }
        if (!isNaN(qtyB)) { totBoxB.textContent = qtyB * priceB; gt += +totBoxB.textContent; }
        if (!isNaN(qtyC)) { totBoxC.textContent = qtyC * priceC; gt += +totBoxC.textContent; }
        if (!isNaN(qtyD)) { totBoxD.textContent = qtyD * priceD; gt += +totBoxD.textContent; }

        grandTot.textContent = gt.toFixed(2);

    }

    function getGrandTotal(){
        calc();
        alert(gt);
    }

    function reset(){

        totBoxA.textContent = "";
        totBoxB.textContent = "";
        totBoxC.textContent = "";
        totBoxD.textContent = "";
        grandTot.textContent = "";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.42em;
    color:#A7A1AE;
    background-color:#1F2739;
}

h1 {
    font-size:3em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height:1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #4DC3FA;
}

h2 {
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    line-height:1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    color: #FB667A;
}

h2 a {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FB667A;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.blue { color: #185875; }
.yellow { color: #FFF842; }

.container th h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #185875;
}

.container td {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container {
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container td, .container th {
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left:2%;
}

/* Background-color of the odd rows */
.container tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #323C50;
}

/* Background-color of the even rows */
.container tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #2C3446;
}

.container th {
    background-color: #1F2739;
}

.container td:first-child { color: #FB667A; }

.container tr:hover {
    background-color: #464A52;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.container td:hover {
    background-color: #FFF842;
    color: #403E10;
    font-weight: bold;

    box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
    transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);

    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .container td:nth-child(4),
    .container th:nth-child(4) { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Open you browser developer tools (usually pressing F12 key will open it) and check you have any error.

Comment: Nope, it is not java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing a lot of things in your code, it works :)
The main issue was within your code logic, you just blindly copied the code without knowing how it works.
You are getting this element but it didn't exists `var grandTot = document.getElementById('grandTotal');` and rest of the code in `getGrandTotal()` didn't work because of the null error.

I Just added this line in html and created that element with id `grandTotal`

```
<td id="grandTotal"></td>
```

```js
var qtyBoxA = document.getElementById('QtyA');
      var qtyBoxB = document.getElementById('QtyB');
      var qtyBoxC = document.getElementById('QtyC');
      var qtyBoxD = document.getElementById('QtyD');
      var totBoxA = document.getElementById('TotalA');
      var totBoxB = document.getElementById('TotalB');
      var totBoxC = document.getElementById('TotalC');
      var totBoxD = document.getElementById('TotalD');
      var grandTot = document.getElementById('grandTotal');
      var btnGetTot = document.querySelector("input[type=button]");
      var btnReset = document.querySelector("input[type=reset]");
      qtyBoxA.addEventListener("change", calc);
      qtyBoxB.addEventListener("change", calc);
      qtyBoxC.addEventListener("change", calc);
      qtyBoxD.addEventListener("change", calc);
      btnGetTot.addEventListener("click", getGrandTotal);
      btnReset.addEventListener("click", reset);
      var gt = null;

      function calc() {
        var priceA = 3;
        var priceB = 4;
        var priceC = 5.50;
        var priceD = 5.50;
        gt = 0;
        var qtyA = parseInt(qtyBoxA.value, 10);
        var qtyB = parseInt(qtyBoxB.value, 10);
        var qtyC = parseInt(qtyBoxC.value, 10);
        var qtyD = parseInt(qtyBoxD.value, 10);
        if (!isNaN(qtyA)) {
          totBoxA.textContent = qtyA * priceA;
          gt += +totBoxA.textContent;
        }
        if (!isNaN(qtyB)) {
          totBoxB.textContent = qtyB * priceB;
          gt += +totBoxB.textContent;
        }
        if (!isNaN(qtyC)) {
          totBoxC.textContent = qtyC * priceC;
          gt += +totBoxC.textContent;
        }
        if (!isNaN(qtyD)) {
          totBoxD.textContent = qtyD * priceD;
          gt += +totBoxD.textContent;
        }
        grandTot.textContent = gt.toFixed(2);
      }

      function getGrandTotal() {
        calc();
      }

      function reset() {
        totBoxA.textContent = "";
        totBoxB.textContent = "";
        totBoxC.textContent = "";
        totBoxD.textContent = "";
        grandTot.textContent = "";
      }
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.42em;
  color: #A7A1AE;
  background-color: #1F2739;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4DC3FA;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  color: #FB667A;
}

h2 a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FB667A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blue {
  color: #185875;
}

.yellow {
  color: #FFF842;
}

.container th h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #185875;
}

.container td {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container td,
.container th {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

/* Background-color of the odd rows */
.container tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #323C50;
}

/* Background-color of the even rows */
.container tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #2C3446;
}

.container th {
  background-color: #1F2739;
}

.container td:first-child {
  color: #FB667A;
}

.container tr:hover {
  background-color: #464A52;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.container td:hover {
  background-color: #FFF842;
  color: #403E10;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
  transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {

  .container td:nth-child(4),
  .container th:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="blue">&lt;</span>faiz <span class="blue">&gt;</span>
  <span class="yellow">pizza</span>
</h1>
<form>
  <table class="container">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h1>Pizza</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Image</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Quantity</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Price</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Total</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>margherita</td>
      <td>
        <img src="Pizza_Margherita_stu_spivack-removebg-preview.png" alt="margherita" height="400" width="400">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="QtyA">
      </td>
      <td>€3.00</td>
      <td id="TotalA"></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tuna</td>
      <td>
        <img src="Tuna_Treat-7268.png" alt="Tuna" height="400" width="400">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="QtyB">
      </td>
      <td>€14.00</td>
      <td id="TotalB"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fourcheese</td>
      <td>
        <img src="4_Cheese-7262.png" alt="fourcheese">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="QtyC">
      </td>
      <td>€5.50</td>
      <td id="TotalC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>double pepperoni</td>
      <td>
        <img src="Double_Pepperoni-7260.png" alt="pep" height="400" width="400">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="QtyD">
      </td>
      <td>€5.50</td>
      <td id="TotalD"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pizza</td>
      <td>ef</td>
      <td>fwrf</td>
      <td>ref</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>refe</td>
      <td>erf</td>
      <td>erf</td>
      <td>ref</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Get Grand Total">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
      </td>
      <td id="grandTotal"></td> <!--- This is the line I added ---->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </form>
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: thanks for the solution i didnt copy the code am still learning and trying to make code myself